# Algorithm logic

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

I am stuck in a problem, and failing to put a logic here, hope you guys can help me. Somebody had asked same kind of problem here on stackoverflow and i am unable to locate the link, its very much similar to the query which was posted

I am generatng a report, where the user select dates/date and on the basis of that 
values are getting fetched from the database and showing in the report. Apache poi is being used for generating excel report.

I have 4 fields/Columns

```
ID      Date        true/false   someaction
```

If the user selects only one or more than one date, The programme takes all the dates and store them in a Arraylist and then iterate it to get data stored in the database the selected date

**PseudoCode**

```
 String checkLastCell = null;

    for (Date listOfdates : datesL){

            //query gets fired to the database by sending listOfdates as a parameter

            for ( T tt : t) {

                i = tt.getId(); //ID
                j = tt.getDate(); //Date
                k = tt.getTrueFalse(); // truefalse 


            and setting them on cells 

            for column l , i am writing some action based on the 
            l= Yes or No  //someaction Yes or No
```

- for Id =1 , if  True is set in truefalse column, i need to write Yes in Someaction column
- In the next iteration, if the id = 2 , and False is set in truefalse column, i will write No in someaction column,
- if in the next iteration, Id =1 and False is set in truefalse columns, I need to check the previous action for ID=1 and then write the action -> No ( because its changed from True to False)

> if (lastcell is Null && t.getTrueFalse().equals("true") || lastcell is
>   not null && t.getTrueFalse().equals("true"))
>   if if (lastcell is Null && t.getTrueFalse().equals("false") ||
>   lastcell is not null && t.getTrueFalse().equals("false"))     { set the
>   action as NO  }
>   .....some more logic needs to written here.
>
> ```
>       i++; // increment the row       }
>           }   }
> ```

i need suggestions/help in writing the pseudocode/algo

Comment: Can you give some example input and desired output?

Comment: Your example is extremely confusing. It would help if you told use what the someaction column actually means. Also, which part of the problem are you stuck with? Is it designing the algorithm or implementing it?

Comment: I'd suggest you use some more meaningful names, e.g. `truefalse` indicates a boolean flag but what is its _meaning_? Try to find some reasonable names for variable to make reading and understanding your code easier (also variable names like `i`, `j` and  `k` are way too generic in your case). - Additionally, setting yes or no as the values of `someAction` indicates it is a boolean field as well. Is that correct?

Comment: truefalse doesn't indicate boolean value, pardon me for making it a confusing problem. it just indicates if the system is Up (true) or Down(false). i need to compare ID's and this columns and write an action according to it.

Comment: My problem is there might be heaps of ID's present in single date record, and if there are multiple dates being selected, how the performance issue will be handled.

Comment: i am stuck in designing the algo

Answer (score 0):

You just need a HashMap (java) to hold the index of the last row containing the ID. Here's the algorithm/implementation.

```
List<Row> dbResults = getDatabaseResults(listOfDates);
HashMap<int, int> idToLastIndex = new HashMap<int, int>();
for(int x=0; x<dbResults.size(); x++) {
    // values
    i = dbResults[x].getID();
    j = dbResults[x].getDate();
    k = dbResults[x].getTrueFalse();
    // get action value
    if(idToIndex.containsKey(i) && k == dbResults.get(idToLastIndex.get(i)).getTrueFalse()) {
        // if there's an old value and it equals the new one
        a = "NO ACTION TAKEN";
    } else if(k == true) {
        a = "YES";
    } else {
        a = "NO";
    }
    idToLastIndex.put(i, x); // ID->Index
}
```

*NOTE* The above code was written in the web browser and was not tested, syntax errors may be present.

Comment: Thanks for the algo, i have a small doubt ,that would hold the result for a single date right? what if user is selecting multiple dates, this loop would work for a single date, on the next date, i would like to check the condition again with previous date. I m not sure, but would vector work?

Comment: @Gaurav - if I'm understanding you correctly, you would just need to move the HashMap<int, int> line above your date loop. This way idToLastIndex would be in scope for all of your dates.